# Extract data from a paginated API with tRESTClient

Tags: json, pagination, talend

I need to crawl a paginated REST API with `offset` and `limit` parameters using [Talend](http://www.talend.com).
The API gives me a list of the resources I am interested in.

For instance, the response to the initial request with `offset=0` and `limit=2` is:

```
{

    "meta": {
        "limit": 2,
        "next": "/api/v1/request/?offset=2&limit=2",
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 4300
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the response object contains an `objects` key, i.e. some of the desired resources and a `meta` key which indicates the next URL to query: `next`. So far I am able to perform the initial request with `tRESTClient`. However, I don't know how to proceed from here and request the remaining pages using the clue given by `next`.

**How can I** perform multiple requests to that API so that I **iterate over the whole list until `next` equals `null` (=list is exhausted)?**

I tried to figure out how tSetGlobalVar and tLoop could help me, but so far with no success. But then again, I am a Talend newbie.

### Current job

This is what my job currently looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the current job]

Comment: Have you consider using the tLoop component ?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see how to wire this up with the `tRESTClient` component. For example, `tRESTClient` does not accept an incoming `Iterate` connection. I also tried to build a job hierarchy similar to the one in the [`tLoop` documentation](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/viewpage.action?pageId=13812567), but I couldn't figure out how to access the `CURRENT_VALUE` in the subjob.

Comment: try using tRest instead of tRestClient. This will help for sure. I don't have time to write a full and complete answer right now : http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=30402